# YouTube API with https: "Google_IOException: p roblem with the SSL CA

Tags: php, https, youtube, youtube-api

Short form: I've got some PHP code that is uploading videos from my site to YouTube.  I'm using the usual Google-provided PHP library, `google-api-php-client`.  I have this code running on two servers; it works on one (https://www.example.com) but has suddenly stopped working on the other (https://dev.example.com), after a period of working nicely.

Details: The code doing the transfer is relatively standard, as far as I can tell:  Once the libraries are loaded and some variables get some values, I'm doing:

```
$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setClientId($youtube_client_id);
$client->setClientSecret($youtube_client_secret);
$redirect = filter_var('https://example.com/upload-to-youtube', FILTER_SANITIZE_URL);
$client->setRedirectUri($redirect);
$youtube = new Google_YoutubeService($client);
$client->authenticate();
header('Location: ' . $redirect);
```

For the server that's not working, the `$client->authenticate` line throws the error:
`Google_IOException: HTTP Error: (0) Problem with the SSL CA cert (path? access rights?) in Google_CurlIO->makeRequest() (line 128 of /var/www/html/example/includes/google-api-php-client/src/io/Google_CurlIO.php).`

Other possibly-relevant details:

- Back in the Developer's Console for my YT application, I have the following Redirect URIs set up:

  https://dev.example.com/delete-from-youtube

  https://dev.example.com/upload-to-youtube

  https://www.example.com/delete-from-youtube

  https://www.example.com/upload-to-youtube
- According to the SSL certificate tester I found at https://www.sslshopper.com/ssl-checker.html, the certificates on both sites are visible and valid.
- The certificate for dev.example.com is from Comodo; the certificate for www.example.com is from GeoTrust.  I suppose I could try getting a new cert from GeoTrust, but I'd rather not spend the money unless I know it will fix the problem.
- Both servers are running the same version of curl, if that's relevant.

It seems (to me) that the certificate and access to it should be OK (unless the certificate tester is wrong), so I don't understand where the complaint is coming from.  The code and the server configuration has been unchanged for quite a while, hence my search for an external explanation.  (I understand that these are Famous Last Words, but whatever.)  Any thoughts out there?  Thanks!

Comment: I have the exact same error, similar code, different google api.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Potential duplicate question:
[Amazon MarketplaceWebServiceOrders requests suddenly failing, PHP curl giving SSL CA cert error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26099849/amazon-marketplacewebserviceorders-requests-suddenly-failing-php-curl-giving-ss)

I had to restart the server, not just apache in order to solve the issue.

Comment: Yup, that was it.  I had already dealt with bash, but hadn't rebooted the server.  Once I did that, things are working again.  Thanks!