# Amazon MarketplaceWebServiceOrders requests suddenly failing, PHP curl giving SSL CA cert error?

Tags: php, ssl, curl, ca

Starting at 4am Sunday, we suddenly started seeing errors from curl, from the `Marketplace Web Service Orders PHP5 Library` `MarketplaceWebServiceOrders/Client.php` script:

```
Caught Exception: Internal Error
Response Status Code: 0
Error Code: 
Error Type: 
Request ID: 
XML: 
ResponseHeaderMetadata: RequestId: , ResponseContext: , Timestamp:
```

The actual curl error number is `77`, with the message being:

```
Problem with the SSL CA cert (path? access rights?)
```

Interestingly, when I test with `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);` I still get the same error. I also get the same error when using the following options:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CAPATH, '/etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt');
```

It strikes me odd that this just suddenly stopped working this weekend. We haven't changed the code, nor has the server had any updates run at that time. How can I go about fixing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We had the exact same problem this morning. It seems it has something to do with the bash update from last weekend.

We fixed the problem by simply restarting apache.

Edit:

For more information about the bash update you can also check http://www.troyhunt.com/2014/09/everything-you-need-to-know-about.html

Comment: Graceful and regular restart for apache did not work for us.  Restarting the server did.