# CurlException: 77: Prblem with the SSL CA cert on facebook login

Tags: php, facebook, curl, sdk

I'm trying to launch login system with facebook using facebook PHP SDK, but I get this error:

```
CurlException: 77: Problem with the SSL CA cert (path? access rights?)
```

I have tried it on another server and it worked brilliantly.
On this server where it does not work I have tried everything I could find on the Internet. I have tried these solutions:

- http://ahoj.io/facebook-php-api-without-curl-extension
- adding fb_ca_chain_bundle.crt (yes, I chmoded 777 the file and the directory)
- adding cacert.pem
- adding `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);` before `curl_exec()`

None of these worked. Is it possible that hosting providers could solve this issue? Because a few days ago this script worked brilliantly on both test servers.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26099849/amazon-marketplacewebserviceorders-requests-suddenly-failing-php-curl-giving-ss

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Recently, Facebook changed its encryption, so I installed Mcrypt extension and it works again.